# visual studio 2015 VSPackage did not load correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2015

We are developing and testing a C# program, my installation of Visual Studio 2015 update 2 is reporting "The 'VSPackage' package did not load correctly"

After I opt to contine showing the error message, it is then reporting "'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PasteJson.JsonPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PasteJson' package did not load correctly"

If I then try to clean the build by Build | Clean, I then get a 
"The 'NuGetPackage' package did not load correctly"

So far, we have :-

- tried to apply update 3 without success
- uninstalled and reinstalled without fixing this issue

N.B. We are running in a corporate environment, and have had to rename C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VsHub to VsHub-Suppressed to avoid issues with the company firewall and internet connectivity.

Has any-one else seen these issues ?